# java applet fail when launched with server "incompatible magic value 1013478509"

Tags: java, applet, servlet-3.0

I'm having a problem with my applet. I have a school project where I'm supposed to make a pong-online game. It runs fine offline but when I try to load it from a server I just get an empty frame with a red text in it. when I click the text I get the message:

> incompatible magic value 1013478509

I'm using jetty-all-8.1.8.v20121106.jar, and servlet-api-3.0.jar

The class that starts up the server looks like this:

```
public class TheServer extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; 
    private Scanner sc;
    private String webSite;
    private PrintWriter out;


    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
        resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        out = resp.getWriter();

        sc = new Scanner(new File("F:\\Users\\Johan\\Workspace Kurs 5\\PongOnline\\bin\\pong.html"));
        webSite = "";
        while(sc.hasNext())
            webSite += sc.nextLine();
        sc.close();

        out.println(webSite);
        System.out.println(webSite);
    }

    public static void main(String...args) throws Exception {
        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler( ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
        context.addServlet(TheServer.class, "/");

        Server server = new Server(666);
        server.setHandler(context);
        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @AndrewThompson, very true sorry about that I have been away from stackoverflow for a while. Just solved that. Thanks for reminding me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the  [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html), a proper `.class` file has starts with the *magic number* :

> The magic item supplies the magic number identifying the class file
>   format; it has the value 0xCAFEBABE.

If you open any compiled `.class` file with a hex editor and inspect its first bytes, they should be `0xCAFEBABE`. `1013478509` in ASCII translates to `<htm`.

Make sure you've got the class properly compiled on the server. And more likely, as BalusC already pointed out in his answer, make sure URL's are correct. The `<htm`... bytes you're getting might be an HTML error document served by the server.

Answer (score 11):

The magic value of a valid Java class is `0xCAFEBABE` (the hex value of `3405691582`), which is the first 4 bytes. But you're getting `0x3C68746D` (the hex value of `1013478509`) which in turn stands for the ASCII characters `<`, `h`, `t` and `m`. To see it yourself, run this piece of code:

```
int magic = 1013478509;
ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
b.putInt(magic);
System.out.println(new String(b.array()));
```

This in combination with the applet being served by a website suggests that it's the start of a `<html>` tag which in turn suggests that it's a HTML document.

So, the HTTP request to applet has apparently *actually* returned a HTML document. You should be able to see it yourself when you change the current request URI in browser address bar to point to applet's URL. Then you'll see what the browser *actually* retrieved when it tried to download the applet. Perhaps it's a simple HTTP 404 error document in flavor of a HTML page.

To fix it, just make sure that the URL in the `<applet>` or `<object>` tag is correct. It's relative to the current request URL as you see in browser address bar. The way how your servlet works is quite strange. You're streaming a HTML file from outside the deploy folder. This suggests that the applet is also outside the deploy folder and thus not reachable by a valid URL at all. You should put both the HTML page and the applet in the web content folder. This way you don't need that servlet anymore.

Comment: +1 For pointing out it's probably an HTML error document from the server.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation behind this ridiculous, arcane message. I'd love to know why 'not a class file' was voted down. In our case, we were making a good request for the jar from our page, however the apache rewrite rules were incorrect. So while we were asking for x.jar, and the server had x.jar in the correct location, the rewrite rule was trying to return y.jar to the page.

Answer (score 4):

This means you have a file with the `.class` extension which is not a class. All classes have to start with magic number of `0xCAFEBABE`

The first four bytes of your "class" reads

```
System.out.println(new String(BigInteger.valueOf(1013478509).toByteArray()));
```

prints

```
<htm
```

so I suspect it's a HTML file.