# Applet fail and says incompatible magic value 1008813135 on the website

Tags: java, applet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Incompatible magic value 1008813135](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390733/incompatible-magic-value-1008813135)

I have a servlet class which serves my website with a applet. When i connect to the website (located on my own computer) and waiting for applet to load it fails and says: incompatible magic value 1008813135. What does that mean?

applet tag in the html-file:

```
<applet codebase="bin" code="gui/TickTackToeApplet.class" width=500 height=500>
</applet>
```

The class file is in the java project folder/bin/gui(package)/classfile.class

Here's the html file content:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Henrik's tick-tack-toe game</title>
<center><h1 style="color: white">Tick-Tack-Toe Logo will be displayed here...</h1></center>
</head>
<body bgcolor="black">
<form method="POST" action="/ticktacktoe">
<left>
<SELECT NAME="players">
<OPTGROUP LABEL="Players">
<OPTION VALUE="player">playerName2
<OPTION VALUE="player">PlayerName
</OPTGROUP>
</SELECT>
<input type="SUBMIT" value="Start game">
</left>
<br><br>
<center>
<applet codebase="bin" code="gui/TickTackToeApplet.class" width=500 height=500>
<p>Testing my applet...</p>
</applet>
</center>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Another related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13954714/java-applet-fail-when-launched-with-server-incompatible-magic-value-1013478509

Comment: I've searched and searched, but didnt find any answers that i understand. Im a newbie to programming. Thats why i am asking by myself.

Comment: Do the duplicates help? The browser can't find the class - you need to find out why.

Comment: That's weird. hm.. C:\Users\Henrik\Documents\EclipseProjects\Webbteknologier tenta\TickTackToe\bin\gui\TickTackToe\TickTackToeApplet.class and also got C:\Users\Henrik\Documents\EclipseProjects\Webbteknologier tenta\TickTackToe\bin\gui\TickTackToe\TickTackToeApplet$1.class there