# Bouncycastle and incompatible magic value 1013478509

Tags: java, applet, digital-signature

I developed a java applet for electronic signature by using the library bouncycastle I joined this applet in my web application as a jar but it can not be displayed in a web page and the java console displays this error
"Incompatible magic value 1013478509 in class file org / bouncycastle / jce / provider / BouncyCastleProvider"
who have an idea about this and can help me ??

Comment: The answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13954714/java-applet-fail-when-launched-with-server-incompatible-magic-value-1013478509) may help you.

Comment: i run this applet in a static html page and the new erreur is ""NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/jce/provider/BouncyCastleProvider" although i have the bcprov-jdk15on-152.jar in my applet 
have you an ider @jchamp